# How to send input to a console/CLI program running on remote host using bash?

Tags: bash

I have a script that I normally launch using the following syntax:

```
ssh -Yq user@host "xterm -e '. /home/user/bin/prog1 $arg1;prog2'"
```

(note: I've removed some of the complexities of the command, so please excuse if there are any syntax errors in the `ssh` command; it should not be relevant to the question)

This launches an xterm window that runs `prog1`, and after completion runs `prog2`.  `prog2` is a console-style program that performs some setup, then several seconds later waits for user input.

Is there a way via bash script (preferably without downloading external packages) that I can send data to `prog2` that's running on `$host`?

I've looked into `<<` and `expect`, but it's way over my head.  My intuition is that there's probably a straightforward way of doing this, but I can't figure out what terms to search for.  I also understand that I can remotely send keystrokes to a host using `xdotools` or something similar, but I'm hesitant to request a new package installation unless I know that's the only reasonable solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You can redirect input back into the program e.g. read resp <<< "Hello". Instead of reading keyboard input and putting it in the variable resp. The string "Hello" is redirected into the input leaving you with the variable resp holding the value "Hello"

Comment: When you say "send data to prog2", you mean interact with it but in automated way ? Without a synchronization with prompts from prog2, you may enter into troubles as explained here : http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html. Hence the usefulness of packages like expect.

Comment: Does the xterm have to be running remotely with the commands or can you run the xterm locally with the ssh command? The latter would make it easier to communicate with `prog2` from the local machine.